# Python Insert Image into the middle of an existing PowerPoint

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have an existing PowerPoint presentation with 20 slides. This presentation serves as an template with each slide having different backgrounds. I want to take this (existing) PowerPoint presentation, insert an image in slide number 4 (do nothing with the first 3) and save it as a new PowerPoint presentation.

This is what I have up until now. This code loads an existing presentation and saves it as a new one. Now I just need to know how to use this to insert an image to slide number 4 like described above.

Note: I am using normal Python.

```
from pptx import Presentation

def open_PowerPoint_Presentation(oldFileName, newFileName):
    prs = Presentation(oldFileName)
    #Here I guess I need to type something to complete the task.
    prs.save(newFileName)

open_PowerPoint_Presentation('Template.pptx', 'NewTemplate.pptx')
```

Comment: Is the Powerpoint from open office or microsoft?

Comment: Has the slide nr. 4 already an image?

Comment: It is from Microsoft (if you hover over the tag "powerpoint"  below the post you will see Microsoft in the description.)

Comment: And slide nr. 4 has no image already in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with this module, but I looked at their [quickstart](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)

```
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx import Presentation

def open_PowerPoint_Presentation(oldFileName, newFileName, img, left, top):
    prs = Presentation(oldFileName)
    slide = prs.slides[3]
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img, left, top)
    prs.save(newFileName)

open_PowerPoint_Presentation('Template.pptx', 'NewTemplate.pptx',
                             'mypic.png', Inches(1), Inches(1))
```